# Dynamic variable that needs to access an extension method of it's assigned class

Tags: c#, dynamic, extension-methods

If I had an extension method, for example, like:

```
public static void StringExtensionTest(this string stringer) { MessageBox.Show("This is just a test for stackoverflow"); }
```

With simple test code, like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string overflow = "Only a test";

    dynamic overflowed = "Only a test";

    overflow.StringExtensionTest();

    overflowed.StringExtensionTest();
}
```

How can I get overflowed.StringExtensionTest() to work?  I don't want to use the obvious cast to string, in this example.

Later, in the real project, I'll have multiple objects of different types, which I will assign to a dynamic variable and call the common extension method I added to all these classes.

Comment: What exact is the type of the value stored in `dynamic` variable is determined at runtime. So complier wouldn't know the type when you compile. If you can explain the actual use case then a better approach can be suggested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are getting string from dynamic but it's not casting to string type on runtime use following code it will help and tested.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Test.overflow.StringExtensionTest();
        ((string)Test.overflowed).StringExtensionTest();
    }

public static class Test
{
    public static string overflow = "Only a test";
    public static dynamic overflowed = "Only a test";
    public static void StringExtensionTest(this string stringer) { MessageBox.Show("This is just a test for stackoverflow"); }
}
```

First Dialog

[image]

Second Dialog

[image]

Comment: Thank you, for the answer.  I didn't mention, I don't want to cast the dynamic variable.  In my project, I'd need multiple IS and AS.  Sorry, that was my fault.

Answer (score 0):

If the extension method for each possible type is defined in the same class, then you can just call it as a static method:

```
SomeClass.StringExtensionTest(overflow);
```

Otherwise though, extension methods don't make much sense in the context of `dynamic`. Extension methods add methods to the set of methods that might be found depending on what namespaces are in use in the C# file the call is in. There's no equivalent to namespaces or C# files in running code.

Comment: I'd have to determine, what the type of class it is and I don't want to do that.  I can can have a bunch of if statements or a switch and say Object IS class.  I can access all the properties and fields of whatever object, I assign to the dynamic variable.  So, it knows what type it is and in my opinion should call the extension methods.  Take dynamic out of the language, if you're not gonna give 100% functionality.  See what I'm saying.

Comment: Which extension methods? There have been none introduced through `using` statements and referenced libraries in the piece of code, because there are no `using` statements in effect in dynamic code.